# How to display rating bar value in textview

Tags: android, textview, rating, ratingbar

i tried to display the user's rating in a textview and all i'm getting is the 'process terminated unexpectedly' error. There are three activities. The XML coding of the activity containing the rating bar is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
tools:context=".RatingActivity" >

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView3"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
     android:layout_centerVertical="true"
     android:hint="@string/hello_world"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

and the java coding is:

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.app.Activity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.RatingBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class RatingActivity extends Activity 
{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_rating);
    RatingBar ratingBar1=(RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);
    TextView textView3 =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
                textView3.setTextSize(40);
                textView3.setText("Rating is :"+ratingBar1.getRating());

}

}
```

What am i doing wrong? I am new to android application development. Please help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RatingBar mBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.mRatingBar);
mBar.setOnClickListener(onclickbutton1);

public void onClick(View v) {

    RatingBar bar = (RatingBar) v;
    statusMessage.setText("value is " + bar.getRating());
}
```

Comment: well i know i'm doing something wrong, could you please help me with that..?

Comment: Do you want the text view to have the rating bar value as soon as the user rated ? then you need a listener as the code above

Comment: on click listener allow you to set text view value as soon as the rating bar was clicked

Comment: actually the project has three activities and in the second one after giving the rating the user clicks the rate button which creates an intent and open the rating activity where it should show the rating in textView. I used findViewById and get the rating using the getRating()..

Comment: ok then you have to send the rating value in the intent to the next activity to set the value to a text view

Comment: i see, so i cannot get the rating directly? And i did try sending the rating value and used a float variable to catch the value in the rating activity, but it didn't work then.

Comment: No, if you rated in one activity and the text view is in another activity then you need to send the rating value to the activity where text view is located

Comment: So, could you please tell me how to do it? Is my method right?   public void sendRating(View view) 
 {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(this, RatingActivity.class);
        RatingBar ratingBar1 = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar1);
     float rating = ratingBar1.getRating();
     intent1.putExtra(RATING, rating);
     startActivity(intent1);
 }

Comment: Yes its right, but change this  intent1.putExtra("RATING", rating);

Comment: and in the RatingActivity u need to get the intent ---> Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
if (extras == null) {
    return;
    }
String value1 = extras.getFloat(RATING);
if (value1 != null) {
  // Do something with the data --> set your text view
}

Comment: Hope this helped, if yes please choose my answer and vote up for me, and if no tell me what was the problem

Comment: It gives an error that float value cannot be converted to string and can u please tell me why i should give "RATING"?

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but keeping "RATING" was causing trouble because it didn't pass the value through properly ,and all i had to do was typecast from float to string.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have view with id `ratingBar1` in you layout file.

Comment: actually the project has three activities and in the second one after giving the rating the user clicks the rate button which creates an intent and open the rating activity.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [setOnRatingBarChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html#setOnRatingBarChangeListener(android.widget.RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener)) for a better performance:

```
    myRatingBar.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser) {
            myTextView.setText(String.format("%2.1f", rating));
        }
    });
```